# Is the std::vector copied or moved in this case?

Tags: c++

In the following code which implements the Viterbi algorithm: ([Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viterbi_algorithm#Pseudocode))

```
std::pair<std::vector<index_t>, float> viterbi_get_optimal_path(const SoundGraph &g,
                                                      SequenceIter s_first,
                                                      SequenceIter s_last,
                                                      index_t curr_index) {
  if (s_first == s_last) {
    return {std::vector<index_t>({curr_index}), 1.0f};
  }
  std::vector<index_t> seq;
  float prob = 0.0f;
  for (const auto &[next_index, curr_sound] : g.edges(curr_index)) {
    if (curr_sound.sound_ == *s_first) {
      auto [res_seq, res_prob] =
          viterbi_get_optimal_path(g, std::next(s_first), s_last, next_index);
      if (res_prob > 0.0f && curr_sound.prob_ * res_prob > prob) {
        prob = curr_sound.prob_ * res_prob;
        std::swap(seq, res_seq);
        seq.push_back(curr_index);
      }
    }
  }
  return {seq, prob};
}
```

Is the `std::vector<index_t>` copied or moved in this line?

```
      auto [res_seq, res_prob] =
          viterbi_get_optimal_path(g, std::next(s_first), s_last, next_index);
```

I'd like to believe it was moved but I'm not sure.

`index_t` is just `std::ptrdiff_t`

Comment: I think it'll get copied for the `std::pair` constructor, but then the returned `pair` itself gets return value optimized out, and the [structured binding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) creates variables that are rvalue references which shouldn't create any additional copies.

Comment: @NathanPierson Yes, if the return type is just ```std::vector<index_t>```, I'm certain that it will be moved, but ```std::pair``` makes me somewhat uncertain

Comment: Why not test it by printing `&seq[0]` and `&res_seq[0]`? If the vector was moved the address remains the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming C++17 or later, it will be copied once if the function returns via `return {seq, prob};` and moved once if it returns via `return {std::vector<index_t>({curr_index}), 1.0f};`.

You can avoid the copy, by explicitly moving in the return statement:

```
return {std::move(seq), prob};
```

In the most common case such a move of a local variable is implicitly done, but only if the return statement directly (and only) names the variable. That is not the case here, so you need to move manually.

You can potentially avoid the move operations as well by defining `seq` as a `std::pair<std::vector<index_t>, float>` instead and then returning `return seq;`. This so-called *named return value optimization* is not guaranteed, but the compiler is allowed to apply it. To help the compiler apply it, you might then want to make sure that both branches use `return seq;` then. Before applying this blindly, benchmark though. This is a significant enough change that other effects might dominate and end with worse overall result.

Comment: Yes, it is copied (https://wandbox.org/permlink/rt4oS92IZlJj1CVZ), and if I want to move them, I should write ```return {std::move(seq), prob}``` (https://wandbox.org/permlink/FRoIGa1mOMgs86I5). Thanks for clarifying.